# Select first value of Bootstrap Auto Complete

Tags: autocomplete

I am using bootstrap autocomplete with custom resolver.
**I want to select first option programmatically based on response coming from search event function**. I could not find any method to select specific option programmatically in their `API` https://bootstrap-autocomplete.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I have tried playing with following method but it sets the value and then that value starts searching.

```
$('.myAutoSelect').autoComplete('set', { value: myValue, text: myText });
```